# Вывод текстуры в OpenGL

Tags: delphi, opengl, текстура

Прошу посодействовать в решении вопроса по выводу текстуры.
    У меня есть форма Delphi, в которой создан компонент Panel с шириной 800 и         высотой 600 пикселей. В программе я выполняю несколько раз преобразование системы координат. кроме того, я выполняю команду сохранения массива пикселей в текстуру с помощью  glTexSubImage2D с предварительным биндингом и возможностью наложения текстуры glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D). Затем я хочу вывести эту текстуру в квадрат размером 800x600 пикселей с помощью сочетания gltexcoord2f и glVertex3f.

## **Правка от 01.11.19г.**

К сожалению раньше были допущены ошибки в синтаксисе написания команд glTexImage2D и glTexSubImage2D. На данный момент я их подправил но осталась проблема. До того, как выводить текстуру в квадрат, предварительно я рисую в буфер несколько объектов, в том числе и сферу определенным цветом. И после этого при попытке вывести текстуру в квадрат квадрат отрисован тем же цветом что и сфера а должен быть как я понимаю отрисован цветом из buffer. При этом сферы не видно соответственно но виден примитив, который был отрисован ранее. Как мне откорректировать такой непонятный вывод?
    Приведу код записи текстуры в квадрат.
    В переменной buffer хранятся данные о RGB компонентах пикселей(они ненулевые). Однако при выводе в квадрат и дальнейшем сбросе буферов glSwapBuffers на панели я вижу тот же цвет какой был установлен при отрисовке сферы (т.е. как будто значения переменной buffer не используются)
   Что я делаю не так?

```
    glScalef(1,1,1);
    glPixelstorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glGenTextures (1, @texID);
    glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE,texID);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE);
    if schglobal=1 then
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL_BGR, 800, 600, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer)
                   else
                   begin
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL_BGR, 800, 600, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer)
                   end;

    glBegin (GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f (0, 0);
    glVertex3f (vertexes[4,1], vertexes[4,2], vertexes[4,3]);
    glTexCoord2f (1, 0);
    glVertex3f (vertexes[2,1], vertexes[2,2], vertexes[2,3]);
    glTexCoord2f (1, 1);
    glVertex3f (vertexes[1,1], vertexes[1,2], vertexes[1,3]);
    glTexCoord2f (0, 1);
    glVertex3f (vertexes[3,1], vertexes[3,2], vertexes[3,3]);
    glEnd();
```