# glDrawArrays медленнее чем glDrawPixels

Tags: opengl, буферизация

Столкнулся с тем, что glDrawArrays медленнее чем glDrawPixels. 
Что может тормозить работу glDrawArrays. В процедуре я выполняю следующее:
glGenBuffers(1, @cN);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, @cN);
Затем использую glBufferData(...)
...
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,0,width*height);

Comment: Точно не знаю почему так, но рисовать пикселями конечно же накладно, если это не цель. Я как то определил в каких местах массива указать размеры, и теперь рисую треугольниками спрайты.

Comment: @xverizex. Конечная цель скорее всего будет отрисовка текстурой но пока там никак не могу понять как правильно ее привязать с учетом поворотов и переносов. Здесь я описывал этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1038480/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-opengl

Comment: @RobertKazen, но тебе пока glScissor не нужен. Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы можно было рисовать кадры из одного рисунка. Ну это когда в одной картинке несколько кадров. Когда я правильно напишу, то будет хорошо. А пока чтобы вывести один рисунок, то этого кода вполне достаточно. Только это рисуется с помощью шейдеров. Вам надо ещё шейдеры написать, но я могу показать, какой шейдер использовался.